# problem when installing nodemon in node.js

Tags: node.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Vs-Code\Backend\install'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

please cn anyone solve this